# Best practice for changing files automatically once checked in on GitHub

Tags: git, github, githooks, semaphore-ci

We have two environments. This code can't use environment variables, as it's client-side JavaScript.

We need to change a key in an object based on the environment. I don't want to use an if statement because there are multiple places in code.

I only need to change it on the Semaphore CI deployment environment.
I'm thinking maybe post-commit hook might be the best way, and just run a command line tool like `sed` in it to do something like `%s/my_local_web/my_staging_web/g`. I'm open to any suggestions, or alternative ways of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're packaging your front-end code with something like webpack or parcel? Both of these tools (and most of their competitors) support environment-specific configuration:

- [Webpack environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)
- [Parcel environment variables](https://parceljs.org/env.html)

The catch is that environment variables must be provided at *build* time, not runtime. They get compiled into the tools' output.

Comment: Hey Chris! We actually use the TypeScript compiler and so don't use parcel or webpack but if that's the best way, I'll get it working to enable this.

Comment: @jQwierdy, then I think you'll have to add another tool. As far as I can tell, TypeScript doesn't natively support build-time environment variables. However it [does work with just about every build tool out there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html). Today, Webpack is probably the most widely used option, but it's not your only one.